# Are there any simulator programs for Linux like Proteus for Windows to simulate an AVR microcontroller using .hex file?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb

I prefer *Linux* OS because of many tools I used in it and because it is an open source.

I wonder if there is a simulator program like Proteus for *Linux* to **simulate** the microcontrollers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is. Many, but you will find none of them won't do exactly what Proteus does. Some only emulate the AVR itself. Some have a schematic editor so you can attach other components to it like in Proteus. For example SimulIDE and simutron.

Answer (score 0):

You might try to run the Windows program under [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) in Linux.

Comment: Wine for a program like that is probably going to be painfully slow, if it works at all.